# Is $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is complete ? where $d(x,y)=|\exp{x}-\exp{y}|$

Tags: analysis

I tried the sequence $(x_n)=(-n)$ it is a Cauchy sequence but i don't know how to prove that it converge ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To prove that some space is complete, one should show that *any* Cauchy sequence converges.

If you show that the *specific* Cauchy sequence $(x_{n}) = -n$ converges this is insufficient to show that the space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is complete. However if you show that the sequence does not converge, then the metric space would not be complete. So maybe the right thing to do here, is to show that your sequence $x_{n}$ does *not* converge. A good starting point would be to ask to what the sequence could conceivably converge if it did?

(In general, a proof of completeness along the lines you are thinking should start with:

"Let $x_{n}$ be an arbitrary Cauchy sequence...")

Comment: i say that i don't know how to prove that $(x_n)$ do not converge

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Suppose $x_n \to x$ then $\vert e^{-n}-e^x \vert \to 0$.What can you say?

Comment: In your original question you ask how to show that it does converge. I expect there is somewhat of a language barrier. I will update my answer in a moment.

Comment: can i say that $e^x=0$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou  yes! I'll leave it to you to verify that.

Comment: i know that $|e^{-n}-e^x|\leq |e^{-n}|+|e^x|$ and $e^{-n}\rightarrow 0$  but how to deduce that $e^x=0$ ? @MathLover

Comment: Hint: Write $e^{x}$ as sum of two 'obvious' sequences!

Comment: @MathLover i don't know what do you mean

Comment: Write $ \vert e^x \vert \leq \vert e^{x} -e^{-n}  \vert +\vert e^{-n} \vert$.Can you conclude?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57241/discussion-between-math-lover-and-vrouvrou).